# Calling the widget id of a mult-instance widget from inside the widget?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I'm trying to output a unique widget ID inside my mult-instance widgets. So far the following hasn't worked. Is there a unique ID and how do I call it?

Thanks.

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
// outputs the content of the widget
    extract( $args );
    $widget_id = $instance['widget_id'];    
?>
<?php echo $widget_id ; ?>
<?php
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the instance ID with `echo $this->id;` (`$this` is the class instance)

The only time you can't get this id is from the `form()` function, right after you just dropped the widget ([here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/update-widget-form-after-drag-and-drop-wp-save-bug)'s the reason why)

Answer (score 0):

To print the ID in php:

```
echo $this->id;
```

But this will also print the id before it has been added to the sidebar.

So the id will correspond to **`widget-[#]_my_widget-__i__`**

A complementary way to get the widget id is in javascript, after it has been added:

```
$(document).on('widget-added', function(event, widget){
                    var widget_id = widget.context.id;

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer works with recent versions of Elementor (Testing on 3.18.3 2023).

Updated method for getting the widget ID:

```
$this->get_id();
```

Comment: You should explain, wy do you think that this is the correct answer so OP can not only use it, but also understand it.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż because the accepted answer no longer works with recent versions of Elementor. So I added this here for people finding this page in search results and realising that it doesn't work.