# Run JS after widget settings are saved?

Tags: widgets, javascript

I've written a small widget that uses JS for setting up some tabs in the settings panel. Is there a way to re-trigger the tab JS when the widget is done saving?

Looking at the WP [JS source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/js/widgets.dev.js#L230) it doesn't look like it, as it simply blows away the existing HTML & re-renders the entire form. I could potentially overwrite `wpWidgets.save` & do something nutty there but that seems really drastic.

**Solution**

After some hacking based upon One Trick Pony's idea, here's what I ended up with.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if(parseInt("<?php echo $this->number; ?>", 10)) {
        $("[id$='<?php echo $this->id; ?>'] .tabs").tabs();
    }
});
</script>
```

Basically I just send down some JS w/ some Widgets values hardcoded in & do some checks & fun CSS3 selectors to find the right DOM nodes.

Comment: why don't you make the number check with PHP, and include the script only if it's set? ps: [related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/update-widget-form-after-drag-and-drop-wp-save-bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your javascript code inside the widget form, and it will be triggered whenever the widget is refreshed.

If you're tabs are hooked on a click event, a better way would be to use [`$.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the widget instance wrapper. That way you don't need to include the js inside every widget instance...

Comment: I don't need delegation because I'm not listening for any clicks, just need the tabs to be there when the widget is expanded/saved.

Comment: Your method is currently working, but does incur the cost of one extraneous tab setup call (for the copy of the form that WP outputs w/ fake IDs in it). I could do some work to avoid that but it isn't worth it right now. This solution isn't perfect & kinda kludgey but I'll take it, thanks!

Comment: Another solution is to use the [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin to trigger your function whenever a new widget form element is added in the DOM. But I still think you should delegate(). Typical tabs can be styled with CSS, you only need JS for user-interaction - ie. the click handler...

Comment: I'm really not interested in re-implementing tabs, jQuery UI tabs are fine for my needs. I'd rather have some extra junk floating around than doing tabs myself using delegation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but in case someone else winds up here:

There are js actions triggered when widgets are added or saved. Reasonably called `widget-added` and `widget-updated`.

Trac ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19675

You can use them like so:

```
    // On the Widget Actions, run.
$( document ).on( { 'widget-added widget-updated': function ( e, widget ) { //do stuff. }
```