# Using tabs in admin widgets

Tags: widgets, admin, tabs

Update: I should point out that I tested the method below on Plugin/theme options page and it worked perfectly. In-fact I was also able to include the jQuery cookie Plugin to preserve the current tab selection between page loads (nice!).

Been trying to add tabs to an admin widget to reduce the form footprint when you have multiple widget options. I am using the jQuery UI tabs included with WordPress. Here's what I have so far coded into a Plugin.

http://pastebin.com/fe4wdBcp

When the widget is dragged into a widget area the tabs seem to render OK but you can't click to view the second tab. Worse still if you refresh the widgets page the formatting of the tabs is completely lost, and the tabs still don't respond to click events.

Not sure what the problem is here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your pastebin code is no longer accessible. Please update your question or this will be of no help to future users.  It will remain closed until it's been updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using unique IDs (#tabs, #tabs-1 ...), because widgets have multiple instances (the same IDs are used by the instance form the "Available Widgets" area).

So just prepend or append the widget instance ID to your identifiers to make them unique:

```
...
<div id="tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>-1">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>-2">Tab Two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>-1">
        <p><?php _e('Textbox 1') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text1'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($text1); ?>" /></p>
        <p><?php _e('Textarea 1') ?>: <textarea class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea1'); ?>" rows="8" cols="12"><?php echo esc_attr($textarea1); ?></textarea></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>-2">
        <p><?php _e('Textbox 2') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text2'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($text2); ?>" /></p>
        <p><?php _e('Textarea 2') ?>: <textarea class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea2'); ?>" rows="8" cols="12"><?php echo esc_attr($textarea2); ?></textarea></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#tabs-<?php echo $this->id; ?>").tabs();
    });
</script>
...
```

Also, not sure if WP 3.3 fixed [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/update-widget-form-after-drag-and-drop-wp-save-bug) issue, but after the first drag inside the sidebar, the widget-save action needs to be manually triggered for the `id` property to become available inside the form() function.

Comment: Yes, forgot that you need to account for multiple instances of the same widget, duh! I am using $this->id but it only works, as you point out, once the widget has been saved manually. In WP 3.3 the situation (I think?) has been improved slightly as the widget instance id number seems to be there as soon as you drag in a new widget (when inspected with firebug), but it is not available via $this->id.

Comment: What about `$this->widget_id` ? Do a var_dump on `$this` and look for a property that holds a identifier like "widget-bla-bla-32". You can also generate a random one with `uniqid()`...

Comment: Doing a var dump on the whole object the `$this->widget_id` variable doesn't appear to exist. Using `uniqid()` is an interesting idea but also doesn't work; the tabs are still not initialized until you manually save the widget. What I really don't get though is that if you examine the admin ajax requests, there IS a 'save widget' ajax function that executes when you first drag in the widget. BUT, it is only when you manually click to save the widget, and this 'save widget' function fires again, that it works properly! Weird.

Comment: posted a better fix to that bug [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37707/1986) if you're interested...