# Tabbed navigation in widget backend

Tags: widgets, metabox, navigation, tabs

I have just created a widget and i am trying to implement a tabbed navigation in the wp backend but it just seems more difficult than writing all the php code!

The categories metabox is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwQTBas8n_7iOFllSG5QOFg5MTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Google it and you will find how to implement it on front end. You can use same technique to implement it on back end. Example : http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/04/create-tabber-widget-wordpress/

Comment: i've been googling a lot and i know how to write some jquery from scratch to achieve a similar result, it's just that i want to use the same method wordpress uses in its default metaboxes so as to keep ui consistency, thanks for your answer Dalvi

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/using-tabs-in-admin-widgets

Answer (score 0):

I checked the markup and core WordPress code to find out how it handles categories and came to the conclusion that all the categories are get loaded on page load and at a time either All Categories or Most Used is displayed by manipulating it using jQuery(on mouse click showing and hiding category-pop & category-all div).

In core wordpress file **HTML** markup for this is saved in **/wp-admin/press-this.php** file in #taxonomy-category div and **jQuery** is saved in **/wp-admin/js/link.js** file following this // category tabs comment.

By referring his you can develop your widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, after a lot of trial and googling i found a sample metabox from which i took parts of code and at the end it seems it is working.
This is the sample metabox:
https://github.com/PeteMall/Metabox-Tabs/blob/master/jf-metabox-tabs.php