# Update widget form after drag-and-drop "only specific plugin"

Tags: widgets, sidebar

This solution, [Update widget form after drag-and-drop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37707/16964), works correctly but I want to adapt this function to affect only a **specific plugin and not every plugin**. How could I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. When you say "specific plugin," do you mean "one particular widget?"

Comment: Yes, any instance of one particular widget, for example Twitter Widget Pro

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it with the checkmark next to the answer rather than up-voting. Then other people know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update 27 July 2015:*** Added new test to make sure settings.data.search is defined to handle some non-standard sidebar implementations such as WPMU's Custom Sidebars.

---

I ran into this problem with [one of my plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feature-a-page-widget/), and am deeply indebted to [this article](http://www.johngadbois.com/adding-your-own-callbacks-to-wordpress-ajax-requests/) for pointing me in the right direction.

The key is that the third parameter you get in the callback includes the widget's basename (derived from its class). I used a slightly different AJAX function than the example you linked to, but here's what I came up with:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {

    // test to see if any instance of a particular widget is saved
    if( undefined != typeof settings.data.search && settings.data.search('action=save-widget') != -1 && settings.data.search('id_base={YOUR BASENAME GOES HERE}') != -1 ) {
        // do something
    }

    // test to see if any widget was added or re-ordered
    if(settings.data.search('action=widgets-order') != -1) {
        // do something
    }

});
```

A couple notes:

1. Make sure to fill in "{YOUR BASENAME GOES HERE}" above.
2. Note that you can't see which particular widget was added or re-ordered. That's not passed.
3. If you're unsure of your basename, just add `console.log(settings);` to the first line of the function and look at it in a JS browser console. You'll see your basename buried in there.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and your plugin code ["Feature A Page Widget"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feature-a-page-widget/) shows very well how to use it. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help!