# How to refresh Theme Customizer after change color inside wpColorPicker?

Tags: widgets, javascript, theme-customizer, color-picker

I develop my custom widget with setting where I can set up custom color for the widget. I use this code to initialize `wpColorPicker` instead of default text input in `form()` method of Widget class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'bg_color_1' ); ?>').wpColorPicker();
});
```

All works great but if you are trying change the color in Theme Customizer after changing value nothing happens: the Save button still not active and site page not refreshing with the new color.

Previously trying for triggering `change` event, but not working:

```
$('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'bg_color_1' ); ?>').wpColorPicker({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'bg_color_1' ); ?>').change();
    }
});
```

How to reload the page preview (trigger the event when value inside my input have been changed)?

Comment: Try using `wp.customize.previewer.refresh();` in your JS to refresh to preview. ;)

Comment: `$(this).change();` should be enough to work, but you should throttle it and you're probably running into the confusing WP widget javascript initialization issue anyway - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212676/57034 for a working example using wpColorPicker...

Comment: @Aristeides `wp.customize.previewer.refresh();` refreshing works, but WordPress still ignoring my new values in wpColorPicker inputs (they've updating via JS and this point is an issue with Customizer).

Comment: @KolyaKorobochkin Try something like this: https://github.com/aristath/kirki/blob/2.0.5/assets/js/controls/color-alpha.js#L10-L16 The colorpicker may need a delay... at least that's what worked for me. Different use-case, same(-ish) problem.

Comment: @bonger Thank you. Your solution rocks and works :)

Comment: @Aristeides Checkout link above. They using `_.throttle` to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the existing WordPress function to modify color palette like:

```
function my_mce4_options( $init ) {
    $default_colours = '
        "000000", "Black",
        "993300", "Burnt orange",
        "333300", "Dark olive",
        "003300", "Dark green",
        "003366", "Dark azure",
        "000080", "Navy Blue",
        "333399", "Indigo",
        "333333", "Very dark gray",
        "800000", "Maroon",
        "FF6600", "Orange",
        "808000", "Olive",
        "008000", "Green",
        "008080", "Teal",
        "0000FF", "Blue",
        "666699", "Grayish blue",
        "808080", "Gray",
        "FF0000", "Red",
        "FF9900", "Amber",
        "99CC00", "Yellow green",
        "339966", "Sea green",
        "33CCCC", "Turquoise",
        "3366FF", "Royal blue",
        "800080", "Purple",
        "999999", "Medium gray",
        "FF00FF", "Magenta",
        "FFCC00", "Gold",
        "FFFF00", "Yellow",
        "00FF00", "Lime",
        "00FFFF", "Aqua",
        "00CCFF", "Sky blue",
        "993366", "Brown",
        "C0C0C0", "Silver",
        "FF99CC", "Pink",
        "FFCC99", "Peach",
        "FFFF99", "Light yellow",
        "CCFFCC", "Pale green",
        "CCFFFF", "Pale cyan",
        "99CCFF", "Light sky blue",
        "CC99FF", "Plum",
        "FFFFFF", "White"
        ';
    $custom_colours = '
        "e14d43", "Color 1 Name",
        "d83131", "Color 2 Name",
        "ed1c24", "Color 3 Name",
        "f99b1c", "Color 4 Name",
        "50b848", "Color 5 Name",
        "00a859", "Color 6 Name",
        "00aae7", "Color 7 Name",
        "282828", "Color 8 Name"
        ';
    $init['textcolor_map'] = '['.$default_colours.','.$custom_colours.']';
    $init['textcolor_rows'] = 6; // expand colour grid to 6 rows
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce4_options');
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Filter hook referece: [tiny_mce_before_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init)

Answer (score 0):

It's  my same problem which solved with this code:

```
<?php

class my_widget extends WP_Widget 
{
    function __construct() 
    {   
        parent::__construct(__CLASS__, __('Title', TEXT_DOMAIN), array ( 'description' => __( 'Description', TEXT_DOMAIN ), ) );
    
        //...
        
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_footer-widgets.php', array( $this, 'print_widget_scripts' ), 9999 );
    }

    public function enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ) {
        if ( 'widgets.php' !== $hook_suffix ) {
            return;
        }

        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'underscore' );
    }   

    public function print_widget_scripts() {
        ?>
        <script>
            ( function( $ ){
                function initColorPicker( widget ) {
                    widget.find( '.color-picker' ).wpColorPicker( {
                        change: _.throttle( function() { // For Customizer
                            $(this).trigger( 'change' );
                        }, 3000 )
                    });
                }

                function onFormUpdate( event, widget ) {
                    initColorPicker( widget );
                }

                $( document ).on( 'widget-added widget-updated', onFormUpdate );

                $( document ).ready( function() {
                    $( '.widget:has(.color-picker)' ).each( function () {
                        initColorPicker( $( this ) );
                    } );
                } );
                
            }( jQuery ) );
        </script>
        <?php
    }   
}
```